# Convert Date for UI5 table, maybe in bindProperty

Tags: date, odata, sapui5

I have a table with 2 columns: Keys and Values.

The keys are dates, formatted with the sap time format.
Something like this:

```
"/Date(1510700400000)/"
```

I have a function which shows the date in a readable form.

```
        convertDate: function() {
        if (value === 'null') {
            return value.replace('null', 'no date specified')
        } else {
            var d = new Date(parseInt(value.replace('/Date(', '').replace(')/', ''), 10))
        }
        var month = d.getUTCMonth() + 1 // months from 1-12
        var day = d.getUTCDate()
        var year = d.getUTCFullYear()
        return year + '/' + month + '/' + day

    },
```

I access my value via:

```
            oTable2.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
            label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({
                text: "RDATE"
            }),
            sortProperty: "RDATE",
            template: new sap.ui.commons.TextView().bindProperty("text", "key")
        }));
```

Now I want to call my function on "key".

How can I accomplish that? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using a formatter function.

```
 template: new sap.ui.commons.TextView().bindProperty("text", {
    path: "key",
    formatter: function(value){
        if (value === 'null') {
            return value.replace('null', 'no date specified')
        } else {
            var d = new Date(parseInt(value.replace('/Date(', '').replace(')/', ''), 10))
        }
        var month = d.getUTCMonth() + 1 // months from 1-12
        var day = d.getUTCDate()
        var year = d.getUTCFullYear()
        return year + '/' + month + '/' + day
    }
});
```

Reference: https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#/topic/07e4b920f5734fd78fdaa236f26236d8

Comment: thanks, that works! only when I try to return "no date specified" when key == null, that wont work. it gives out:  NaN/NaN/NaN


     formatter: function(key) {
      if (key) {
       var d = new Date(parseInt(key.replace('/Date(', '').replace(')/', ''), 10))
       var month = d.getUTCMonth() + 1 // months from 1-12
       var day = d.getUTCDate()
       var year = d.getUTCFullYear()
       return year + '/' + month + '/' + day
      } else {
       return "asd"
      }
     }

Comment: I am not sure what you're trying to do. Does the older formatter function not work or did you change the code ?

Comment: the old formatter didnt work because of my if statement if value === null. i changed the sequence, and when there is a date, its displayed normally. only for when theres no date specified the formatter is not working